# Accessing to views in changed fragment

Tags: android

I have an activity contains a fragment, i call it `fragment1`. I can access to views of this fragment by `findViewById` and define `setOnClickListener` and `onClick`  methods for them.

It works perfectly. now i change `fragment1` to `fragment2` with fragment transaction. I can define views in `fragment2` with `findViewById` , but when i define `setOnClickListener` and `onClick` methods for them, application crashes. 
what should i do?

ActivityMain onCreate :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

/**button change fragment**/
 Button change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change);
    change.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           final Fragment2 Fr2 = new Fragment2 (); 
           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment1,  Fr2);
           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

/*** This button belongs to fragment1, and it works.**/
 Button Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInBtn);
    Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                  ....
            }
        });

/*** This button belongs to fragment2, and it's not working.**/

 Button Signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUpBtn);
    Signup .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                  ....
            }
        });

}
```

Fragment2 onCreateView :

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_up_form1_fragment,  container, false);
}
```

Fragment1 onCreateView :

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.down_right_fragment,  container, false);
}
```

Comment: post the oncreateVIew of your fragment 2

Comment: i did it. i define them in main activity

Comment: now the oncreateview on fragment 1

Comment: Ok i did it. what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how you set the button onclicklistener on a fragment.. you should get the view from the inflater inside the oncreateView on each fragment and then from there use the view and get the button inside there using the View..

example:

```
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.down_right_fragment,  container, false);



    Button Signup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.SignUpBtn);
    Signup .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
                  ....
            }
        });
    return view;
}
```

Do it the same as your first fragment